# NetSuite customized Customer Login

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

My use case is that I would like customers to log in via a custom Login Form I have created, but not from NetSuite Login which is publicly accessible. How can I achieve that?Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do your own branded custom login page (with your own HTML/CSS), is by creating a `form` that on submit sends a POST request to `https://system.netsuite.com/app/webservices/wslogin.nl?c=######`
where `#####` is your netsuite account number

the form must submit following attributes:

```
email
password
taskid // see the help topic Task Ids for valid values e.g.: LIST_MYROLES
role // not required if has a default role specified on the View All Roles page
```

I don't think that there is a way to block the normal UI login so, that only custom login is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Prasun wrote there are a couple of different approaches to custom login/reg forms.

One is to just hack the login form so that it looks and behaves like you want it to. See the login/registration at http://www.lablearning.com/

The other is to create your own login page using an SSP page and install it to override the built-in login/registration.

Comment: would SSP login be applicable for internal users as well or applicable only for SuiteCommerce logins?

Comment: SSP is mainly for Customer Center Role. But the issue with SSP is that whomever has access to it, also has access to NetSuite backend. Is there a way to have the customers only log in through the SSP, but not the NetSuite Login?

Comment: What is your use case? You can replace the customer login with an SSP so that is the only way for a customer center role to log in. What do you mean by "also has access to the NetSuite backend"? What are you trying to restrict?